# How to Select Count for every user within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table named "Calls". The table's columns are organized as

```
CallCounter, AssignedEmpID, CompletedByEmpID
1            200            200
2            200            200
3            201            200
4            200            200
5            201            201
6            201            200
7            200            200
8            200            200
9            200            201
10           201            201
...
```

How do I create a Select SQL query that will return the following data. Ideally I would like to complete the entire SQL query in 1 query.

```
Employee    # Calls Assigned    # Calls Completed
200         6                   7
201         4                   3
```

I have tried the following queries

```
SELECT AssignedEmpID, COUNT(CallCounter) FROM CALLS
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Calls
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? Is it MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes we are using MSSQL The application is using ODBC Driver 5.1 within C# @PM77-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define a list of employees.  You can do that with a subquery and `union` if you don't have an `employees` table to `join` with.

Then you could use `conditional aggregation`:

```
select t.empid, 
    sum(case when t.empid = c.AssignedEmpID then 1 else 0 end) AssignedCount,
    sum(case when t.empid = c.CompletedByEmpID then 1 else 0 end) CompletedCount
from (select distinct AssignedEmpID as empid from calls 
      union select distinct CompletedByEmpID from calls) t
        join calls c on t.empid in (c.AssignedEmpID, c.CompletedByEmpID)
group by t.empid
```

Comment: The sum command helped me immensely! While your answer wasn't the exact solution to my problem it contained valuable information that helped me solve the original problem. Is sum an expensive call to make? @sgeddes

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a `union all` and `group by`:

```
select EmpId, sum(assigned) as assigned, sum(completed) as completed
from ((select AssignedEmpID as EmpId, 1 as assigned, 0 as completed
       from calls
      ) union all
      (select CompletedByEmpID, 0, 1
       from calls
      )
     ) e
group by EmpId;
```

Another approach is `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(a.EmpId, c.EmpId),
       coalesce(assigned, 0) as assigned, 
       coalesce(completed, 0) as completed
from (select AssignedEmpID as EmpId, count(*) as assigned
      from calls
      group by AssignedEmpID
     ) a full outer join
     (select CompletedByEmpID as EmpId, count(*) as completed
      from calls
      group by CompletedByEmpID
     ) c
     on a.EmpId = c.EmpId;
```